# IDE with specific features

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ide

I'm looking for an IDE that has the following features:

1. Code completion for PHP, HTML, JavaScript+jQuery, CSS
2. JS+CSS minification
3. Mercurial Support
4. Being able to preview the website in different browsers
5. FTP support

The last two are optional, but the first three I really need. Any suggestions?

Comment: Komodo IDE/Edit might have minification as a plugin (it's Mozilla XULRunner-based).

Comment: @Blender: Post that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Cyclone: okay, I shall.

Comment: see and compare all features for php ides at php.idecompare.com

Comment: In this question you don't state which Operating System.

Answer (score 3):

[Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) (payware) and [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) (free) might have CSS/JS minification as a plugin (they are both built off of Mozilla's XULRunner).

From the [features page](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/features) (of the IDE, not Edit), I can confirm:

1. It has support for basically any language you'll ever work with.
2. There seems to be some sort of [minification workaround](http://community.activestate.com/forum/macro-minify-javascript-css-compile-sass-css-fly).
3. Supports: Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Perforce (WTF?), CVS, Bazaar.
4. I doubt it, but you should be able to open browsers with a keyboard shortcut.
5. There's an [FTP addon](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/uploader).

Answer (score 2):

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) IDE has this features (and much more).

Comment: I'm not sure about JS/CSS minification to be honest (and I'm sure #4 is negative), but the rest of the list is covered by PHPStorm.

Comment: Well, Ctrl + Shift + J will join all the lines which is kind of minification. And there is a Web Browsers settings (Settings, IDE Settings) where you can select your browsers to use for project.

Comment: didn't know about the pseudo minification, nice :)